# How to rotate an image of a skewed rectangle?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, image-rotation

I am creating a python program that can analyze an image of a circuit board and identify parts of the image that have a label on them:

[image]

The green text under the labels is what the program is attempting to read from the label. Obviously, it is incorrect due to the label being upside-down or askew. The text is being read by passing the segmented image into `pytesseract.image_to_string`. In order to help the program rotate the image, I added a black border to the label:

[image]

My question is, **how can I align the segmented image so that the rectangle is oriented correctly?** Is this even the right way to go about it? Or would a fiducial work better? I am open to any suggestions that can help me achieve my goal of reading text off these labels. Thank you!

Comment: you could assume it's a panorama aspect ratio, then try OCRing both orientations, then see which one the OCR is more confident in. it should have confidence in the right-side-up letters. -- do yourself a favor, ditch tesseract.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76763025/determine-the-angle-of-the-text-and-the-entire-document-as-a-whole

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this now. What would you recommend instead of tesseract?

Comment: easyocr and paddle are commonly used. honestly, if I needed to build something with OCR in it, I might evaluate those choices, but I also might just start building a custom FCNN instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the corners of the rectangle are, you can use `math.atan2()` to get the angle you need to rotate the image, eg:

```
import math
#TL=(1,2) is the top left corner (arbitrary units)
#TR=(3,4) is the top right corner
rot = -math.atan2(TL[1]-TR[1],TL[0]-TR[0])
rot *= 180/math.pi #if you want degrees instead of radians
```

If you know the angle, there's a lot of libraries that can rotate the image for you, like [Pillow](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-paste-and-rotate-method/#) or [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't know the locations of the corners. The detection boxes are always oriented to axis like in this example: https://ibb.co/M88JLYj The red box is the bounding box of the image.

Comment: @JonZavialov What information can you get about the rectangle? You could get the angle using arctan or something similar if the program can identify any side of the rectangle, or any two specific points at all, really. If you put two individual dots on each label would your program be able to identify those? 

If you can't get any information about the rectangle or anything else, I think the only way to align the image is to just slowly rotate it and test every angle, but that's obviously not ideal.